# Убрать отступ от SelectBox

Tags: html, css

Гуглил, пытался методом тыка, читал, искал, но так и не смог найти, как убрать отступ от SelectBox.
Т.е. отступ идёт не от самого Select,а от его элементов.
Быть может вопрос очень тупой, но я новичек и многочасовые попытки не привели к результату.

```
<form name="******"  method="POST" action="******.php"> 
        <label>Что-то выбрали</label><div class="ComboBox"><select name="comboBox_****" style="color: #fff"></div>
<?php*********?>
        </select> 
        <label>Что-то выбрали</label>
        <div class="ComboBox">
            <select  name="comboBox_****" onchange="showOption(this)" style="color: #fff; background: #111;">
                <option value='***'>Что-то выбрали
                <option value='****'>*******
                <option value='****'>********
                <option value='****'>****
                <option value='****'>****
                <option value='****'>****
            </select> 
         </div>
        <div  id="****" name="****" style="visibility:hidden">
        <label>Введите текст</label><input type="text" name="text" id="styled-select"></input>
        <label>Введите текст </label><input type="text" name="text_" id="styled-select"></input>
        </div>
    </div>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
          function showOption(el)
          {
              if(el.options[el.selectedIndex].value == "*****")
              {
                   document.getElementById("*****").style.visibility = "visible";
              }else
              {
                  document.getElementById("*****").style.visibility = "hidden";
              }
        </script>
        
        <input style="margin-top:0px;" type="submit" id="bth_add" value="Запрос" name="bth_add" class="submit"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Покажите ваш код и как выглядит ваша проблема.

Comment: Добавил в  пост информации

Comment: Хм, какой отступ Вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: @Other Если раскрыть Select---- http://prnt.sc/e7cdcl ,а убрать надо http://prntscr.com/e7ce08